# Port a LWJGL Java Game to XBOX

Tags: java, lwjgl, xbox

Is it possible to create a Java game that was created using LWJGL to the XBOX?

I've seen Minecraft create their game for tons of platforms and I am wondering if I could do the same.

I've seen another person ask a question on if it is possible to create one for Android, but I think that would be easier to do for Android because they support Java by default.

If it is possible to do this, please link me to useful information to how I can do this myself. Also, don't just say "no" if it isn't possible. I want you to tell me why you can't. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. a JVM (runtime that runs your compiled Java code) currently does not exist for the XBOX. You can consider using a language like C# with Unity or C++ with a lower level framework.